# Drag and drop sidebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a new project and I have sidebars I want the user to move around and order them as they want.

Like clicking the header of the box and move it to the top will result the box at the top.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ohekoy/4/edit)*

```
$('.sidebar').draggable();
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
Take a look a **jQuery UI** draggable functionality.